# Subsets of a set, symmetric differences of the form $\{ i , i + 1 \}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A_i = \{i, i + 1\}$. Which subsets of
$\{1, 2, 3, . . . , n \}$ can be written as the symmetric difference of a number of the
sets $A_1, A_2, . . . A_{n−1}$?

Comment: An interesting approach here is to frame this question using linear algebra over $\Bbb F_2^n$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that any subset which contains an even number of elements can be written as such a symmetric difference.

To prove that this is the case, it suffices to prove the following:

- If $S$ contains an even number of elements, then $S \triangle \{i,i+1\}$ also contains an even number of elements
- If $S$ contains an even number of elements, then we can write $S$ as a $k$-fold symmetric difference $S = A_{i_1} \triangle \cdots \triangle A_{i_k}$ for some $i_1,\dots,i_k$ between $1$ and $n-1$.

Comment: I think I proved the first part, but could you elaborate on the proof of the second part?

Comment: For instance: the subset $\{2,4,5,8\}$ can be written as
$$
\Big(\{2,3\} \triangle \{3,4\}\Big) \triangle \Big(\{5,6\} \triangle \{6,7\} \triangle \{7,8\}\Big)
$$
see if you can generalize this construction for an arbitrary set of even size

Comment: So I think I got the second part of the proof as well. One last question: Does this proof naturally exclude all S with an odd number of elements, and if not, what can we do to prove that they cannot be written as a k-fold symmetric difference?

Comment: The first part is there in order to exclude all $S$ with an odd number of elements